# can't display category in prestashop1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hhrZ.png)I am using ps 1.7.
in the category/catalog/sell/back-office.
I add new category and it's sub categories.
But in the front-office or in prestashop, only sample or demo categoris are shown, and the categories i added aren't show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're new to prestashop. Go to modules and select installed modules. Configure the main menu module (ps_mainmenu) to alter your menu.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
you are right.
and one more question, could you tell me which is the best refrence book or guide for ps junior?
i tried to find so much refrence on googling.
but i couldn't find main parts like your answers.
pls help me.

Comment: If you are looking for documentation: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/English+documentation // http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/User+Guide and you can also find a heap of info on the prestashop forum (google it). There are a lot of books, especially on development but those are for prestashop 1.6 (different architecture). You will learn most by going through the admin pages and finding out "what does what". Regards

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
In fact i read and studied your required PS17/User+Guide before, but i couldn't find solution for my problem.
If there is no more better PS1.7 reference, i'll bother you a lot in the future.
and i hope you to answer my questions at that time.
thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome. You can always post a question on stackoverflow but be aware that if you ask too many questions (this is a platorm for developers who help other developers) without contibuting (awnsering questions as well), your account might get suspended. And again, just try as you go and you'll get the hang of it in no-time :)